# Laravel 8 Send Mail by Gmail get stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587/465 (Connection timed out)

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have tried send mail by

MAIL_PORT=587 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AND

MAIL_PORT=465 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

And I allow the option "less secure app"

But always get this notification: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)

And same email and password can send mail in other website.

It's same Framework.

but I don't know why that one site can't send email and other can

My Laravel Version is Laravel Framework 8.34.0 and using ubuntu 20.04

How can I fix this problem Thanks everyone

Comment: What is your encryption mode? in env file

Comment: @MohammadH. I have tried port=587, encryption =tls and port=465, encryption =ssl